# Uploading an image to my server

Tags: php, html, image-uploading

So I want to allow users to upload an image and want to store that image in my server. (Using Ubuntu and Apache) so server path is (/var/www/html/)

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadimages.php" method="POST">
<!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000" />
<!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

and my `uploadimages.php` file code is:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/images';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

When I click the bottom send I get the following message:

`File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => thisisthepictureIupload.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpIUEUjE
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 4596
        )
)`

But when I go to the folder: `/var/www/html/images`  the image is not there.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add a slash at the end of upload directory variable and try. `$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/images/';`

Comment: I already tried that but then I get the error: Possible file upload attack!

Comment: Is there any error message in your log file?

Comment: change your path `$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/images';` to the `$uploaddir = '/html/images';` or `$uploaddir = '/images';`

Comment: Is the images directory writable by the web server?  The folder might be owned by a different user.  777 permissions may be necessary for testing.

Comment: Because the `www` is World wide folder no need to add this to `path` if your file `uploadimages.php` is inside the `HTML` folder than give the paht like this `$uploaddir = '/images';` and if your file  `uploadimages.php` out side the `html` folder than give the path like this: `$uploaddir ='/html/images';`

Comment: I tried: $uploaddir = '/html/images'; and $uploaddir = '/images'; and I get the error: Possible file upload attack!. I think is related to witting permission. How do I grant witting permissions?

Comment: I can write images in both the /temp folder and the /var/www/html/images by copying manually the image and pasting it but I don't know if there are different permission need it when doing it though HTML and PHP

Comment: are you using apache? if so, the folder needs to be able to be written to by the user that apache is running as. if you look in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf you'll see the user/group value with this you can say `chgrp apache /var/www/html/images` then apache can write to that directory

Comment: @misterkoz Not sure if I'm missing any configuration folder. My apache server is working, however, I don't have any file: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf   furthermore I don't even have the folder /etc/httpd/  my Apache is sitting in usr/lib/apache2/  and only has one folder Modules. Under that folder there is a file httpd.exp  but when I opened it it says:  * Please do not edit by hand.

Comment: @SamueldelRio right, i'm working on RHEL based systems, your configuration is likely in /etc/apache or /etc/apache2 - there will be a configuration option that specifies the user and group that apache runs as, the folders that apache host must be visible to that user or it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be missing the `/` in your file path:

```
 $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/images';
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

should probably be

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/images';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . '/' . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Comment: Don't you love it when you're writing an answer and a new answer pops up with your answer in it?

Comment: I tried and I get the "Possible file upload attack!" error.  Here is the whole message I get:   `Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => ImageUploaded.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php7DvRZN
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 4870
        )

)`

Comment: @mister koz  Since I'm getting the message: "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded."  . I think the issue might be related with witting permissions to the folder /var/www/html/images

Comment: what about permissions? Also, please check you have access rights to the tmp folder.

Comment: Do you have SeLinux configured, you may need to add an exemption for that folder path - doesn't seem likely though.

Comment: @misterkoz  Sorry for my illiteracy but I don't know what is SeLinux. I'm thinking though that it is a permission issue. I ran the command `ls -ld /var/www/html/images`  and I get `drwxrwxr-x 2 samuel samuel 4096 Apr  4 15:12 /var/www/html/images`  then I ran the command `ps -aux | grep 'httpd'` and I get `samuel    9490  0.0  0.0  13692  2120 pts/1    R+   13:24   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd`  Thanks again